# What is a c include file and guard?

Tags: c, file, header, include, guard

You must create an include file that contains symbols for DEBUG, TRUE, FALSE, NULL. The include file must contain a guard.--> I have no Idea what is this. When I read it I just see chinese. What is an include file and how can I make it contain symbols for debug, true, false null, WHAT are symbols? haha and ya what is a "guard".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is something that would be answered in the first chapter of any [introductory book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  Or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_file).

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to find out about include guards. And if you don't understand it after doing so, your question could be more specific.

Comment: "WHAT are symbols? haha..." haha indeed. :(

Answer (score 5):

Just to help you out here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html

A guard is a mechanism that's used to avoid re-inclusion of the header files, if the header file is used in multiple source files.

There are various ways to implement a guard, but just an example:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

<Content of the header file>

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple. Its a macro that is used to stop multiple inclusion

**File: guard.h**

```
#ifndef _GUARD
#define _GUARD
    #define DEBUG
    #define TRUE true
    #define FALSE false
    #define NULL 0
#endif
```

The first time the compiler see's this it will `define _GUARD` and the next time it see's it, it will do nothing because `#ifndef` will be false.

Comment: Thanks I guess this is it but what is the role of DEBUG,TRUE,FALSE and NULL in the header file?

Comment: So that anywhere you `#include "guard.h"` you can now use the symbols.

Comment: The preprocessor we replace all your TRUE by true in your code (FALSE by false, NULL by 0). If in your code you have : if(my_function()==NULL) it will be for the compiler : if(my_function()==0). For the #define DEBUG it is useful to define debug part in your code using #ifdef DEBUG.